# Android get bluetooth address in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-6.0-marshmallow, mac-address

blutooth address and wifi address (`mac`) are depracted since android 6 
marshmallow .

```
bluetooth.getAddress();
```

how we can get unique number from android device such as bluetooth address or wifi mac address ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access to the mac address has been **deliberately removed**:

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html

use this code :
get the mac address via reflection or Settings.Secure:

```
 String macAddress = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_address");
```

Comment: Is this save to use? Does my app gets banned from the play store if I do this?